# Ayuda con evento RowDataBound en Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente evento en un gridview en el cual necesito pintar la celda de amarillo si su valor es menor a 50%, pero pinta todo de amarillo

```html
<asp:BoundField DataField="AvanceTotal" HeaderText="Avance%" ReadOnly="True" 
SortExpression="AvanceTotal" DataFormatString="{0:P2}" />
```

```html
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
try
{
string var = Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells[6]);
int x = 0;
Int32.TryParse(var, out x);
if (x < 0.5)
{
e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
}
catch (Exception ex) { ex.ToString(); }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tomar el valor de la celda si esta es un `BoundField` es por medio de la propiedad `Text` por lo tanto deberias usar

```
e.Row.Cells[6].Text
```

Salvo que sea de template ahi cambia porque debes acceder al control usando el `FindControl()`, pero en tu caso se usa el `Text`

Lo que sucede es que ningun valor esta pudiendo se convertido a `numerico`, porque ademas veo que le pones un `%` a la celda, eso puede ser un problema

```
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string avance = e.Row.Cells[6].Text;

        int x = 0;
        if(int.TryParse(avance, out x))
        {
            if (x < 0.5)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        ex.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Recueda que el `TryParse()` indica si la conversion pudo realizarse